# Flink Aggregation Function not working, getting StreamTaskException: cannot load user class Accumulator

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.15 and trying to use the user defined Aggregation function with Table Api. Can't seem to get it to work, getting the error. StreamTaskException: cannot load user class IValueAccumulator. class not resolvable through given class loader.

Here is the Aggregation function:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.DataTypes;
import org.apache.flink.table.catalog.DataTypeFactory;
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.AggregateFunction;
import org.apache.flink.table.types.DataType;
import org.apache.flink.table.types.inference.InputTypeStrategies;
import org.apache.flink.table.types.inference.TypeInference;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;


public final class IValueAggregation extends AggregateFunction<Row, IValueAccumulator> {
          
    @Override
    public Row getValue(IValueAccumulator accumulator) {
        return Row.of(accumulator.value);
    }

    @Override
    public IValueAccumulator createAccumulator() {
        return new IValueAccumulator();
    }

     /**
     * Declares the {@link TypeInference} of this function. It specifies:
     *
     * <ul>
     *   <li>which argument types are supported when calling this function,
     *   <li>which {@link DataType#getConversionClass()} should be used when calling the JVM method
     *       {@link #accumulate(Accumulator, Object, LocalDate)} during runtime,
     *   <li>a similar strategy how to derive an accumulator type,
     *   <li>and a similar strategy how to derive the output type.
     * </ul>
     */
    @Override
    public TypeInference getTypeInference(DataTypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return TypeInference.newBuilder()
                // accept a signature (ANY, DATE) both with default conversion classes,
                // the input type strategy is mostly used to produce nicer validation exceptions
                // during planning, implementers can decide to skip it if they are fine with failing
                // at a later stage during code generation when the runtime method is checked
                .inputTypeStrategy(
                        InputTypeStrategies.sequence(
                                InputTypeStrategies.explicit(DataTypes.FLOAT())))
                // let the accumulator data type depend on the first input argument
                .accumulatorTypeStrategy(
                        callContext -> {
                            //final DataType argDataType = callContext.getArgumentDataTypes().get(0);
                            final DataType accDataType =
                                    DataTypes.STRUCTURED(
                                        IValueAccumulator.class,
                                            DataTypes.FIELD("value", DataTypes.FLOAT()));
                            return Optional.of(accDataType);
                        })
                // let the output data type depend on the first input argument
                .outputTypeStrategy(
                        callContext -> {
                            //final DataType argDataType = callContext.getArgumentDataTypes().get(0);
                            final DataType outputDataType =
                                    DataTypes.ROW(
                                            DataTypes.FIELD("value", DataTypes.FLOAT()));
                            return Optional.of(outputDataType);
                        })
                .build();
    }
    public void accumulate(IValueAccumulator accumulator, Float signal_value) {        
        accumulator.value += signal_value;
    }

    public void resetAccumulator(IValueAccumulator accumulator) {
        accumulator.value = 0.0F;
    }
    
}
```

Here is the accumulator class:

```
public class IValueAccumulator {
    public Float value;
}
```

Where I register the aggregation function

```
tableEnv.createTemporaryFunction("InstantSum", IValueAggregation.class);
```

Where the aggregation function is called with windowing and groupby:

```
var windowedResult = mergedStreamTable
                                    .where($("merged_stream_id").isEqual(currentMergedStreamId))
                                    .window(Tumble.over(lit(10).minutes())
                                    .on($("rowtime"))
                                    .as("w")) // define window
                                    .groupBy($("signal_type"), $("signal_name"), $("w")) 
                                    .aggregate(call("InstantSum", $("signal_value")).as("sum_signal_value"))
                                    .select($("signal_type"), $("signal_name"), $("sum_signal_value"), $("w").start().as("window_start"), $("w").end().as("window_end"));
```